# Sprite Jump in my Game Play Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Hy, I have started a Game in andengine for android, I want to apply a jump functionality on a sprite which will be like some projectile motion , up and forward as well . I have applied move modifier to gain that functionality. But that is not in projectile motion.

How can i achieve that and while the jump of my sprite by tapping again it cant jump again until it completes it jump.i dont want to use delay function on scene touch .any help .

```
final Entity playerEntity = move;
final float jumpDuration = 1;
final float startX = playerEntity.getX();
final float jumpHeight = 60;
move.getTextureRegion().setFlippedVertical(true);
final MoveModifier jumpForwardUp = new MoveModifier(jumpDuration/2, startX, startX - jumpHeight, playerEntity.getY(), playerEntity.getY() + 130);
final MoveModifier jumpForwardDown = new MoveModifier(jumpDuration/2, startX - jumpHeight, startX, playerEntity.getY() + 130, playerEntity.getY() + 170);
final SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(jumpForwardUp ,jumpForwardDown);
playerEntity.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JumpModifier` and for some real physics work, go for `Box2d Extension` of `AndEngine` and go through some of `AndEngine` examples code.

**Edit:**

`AndEngine` have list of modifiers. `JumpModifier` is one of them. Maintain a class level or project level `flag` that is `true` when your object is in jump and is `false` when object is in normal state.

Every modifier takes an object of `IModifierListner` set that `flag` to `true` in `onStart` of `IModifierListner` and set that to `false` at `onEnd` of `IModifierListner`. at every tap check if that `flag` is `true` then simple `return` and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks For reply.
Didnt get any JumpModifier can you give a reference?
It can be done by Physics Box2d I know , Thinking may be some other options without using physics,Well i Will do it with Box2d But what is the solution for continuous tapping ? how can i avoid a jump if it is already jumping on touch ?